# Model methods with NGXS

Tags: angular, class, interface, model, ngxs

I'm starting to integrate NGXS into my Angular project, and am facing a bit of a dilemma.

Currently, all my models are classes, which also contain methods that deal with the model (helper methods, as well as actions).
I'm aware of the fact that with NGXS, the actions should not be in the model objects and should move to the actions/states files.
However, I'm not sure what to do with the other methods.

On the one hand, placing them inside the services seems artificial, as the services are used mostly for CRUD operations. Moreover, every tutorial I can find regarding Angular that does not include NGXS, advocates the use of model classes encapsulating the model's funtionality.

On the other hand, all of the NGXS examples I've seen so far use only interfaces as models.

Here's an example model class:

```
export class Person {

    static readonly ADULT_TIME = 18 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    name: string;
    dateOfBirth: Date;

    constructor(name: string, dateOfBirth: Date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public isAdult(): boolean {
        return (Date.now() - this.dateOfBirth.getTime()) >= Person.ADULT_TIME; 
    }
}
```

An interface of such a model would be:

```
export interface Person {
    name: string;
    dateOfBirth: Date;
}
```

Is there some standard approach as to what to do with the model related methods when working with NGXS (e.g. `isAdult()`), or alternatively, is it possible/advisable to work with model classes alongside NGXS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is to use interface/object literals for the state model.
If you want a richer model, you can transform from what is stored in the state using a `Selector`.

[Here](https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/700) is a discussion re: classes or interfaces on the NGXS Github page. It also shows some suggested workaround options.

Comment: I've read the discussion (thanks for pointing it, b.t.w), and although I do have some questions regarding performance and naming conventions, which I've raised in GitHub, this does answer my question and solves my problem. Thanks a lot !